# How to remove or change the default help command?

Tags: python, discord.py

How do you remove or at least change the format of the default help command in discord.py?

I think changing the format would be nice, I don't really like the format at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
bot.remove_command('help')
```

Put this at the top of your code, after your imports.
Then create your own.

Or to format it check this out: [Click here!](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/967d43c35b4d4c288d47a9eb9d374bef34292f1d/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L91-L143)

Comment: Please edit your post to be more specific. You link to a file in the source code, but you didn't say what to do with it.

Answer (score 15):

The proper way to disable the help command according to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.help_command) is to pass `help_command=None` into the constructor for `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, such as:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(help_command=None)
```

or

```py
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(help_command=None)
```

This also allows you the opportunity to pass your own help function into the `help_command` argument for different formatting.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to remove the command for example

```
client.remove_command('help')
```

you will need to put it under

```
client = commands.Bot
```

it will be like

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'somethingelse')
client.remove_command('help')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()

activity = discord.Game(name=f"!help in {len(client.guilds)} servers!")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, activity=activity, status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, help_command=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you should do it so that it preserves the behavior of the help command while letting you change how it looks:

````
class MyHelpCommand(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return '{0.clean_prefix}{1.qualified_name} {1.signature}'.format(self, command)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self._original_help_command = bot.help_command
        bot.help_command = MyHelpCommand()
        bot.help_command.cog = self

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.bot.help_command = self._original_help_command```
````

See the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#help-commands for more details.

For migrating from old helpformatters: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#helpformatter-and-help-command-changes

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need to remove the command... It isn't good, using the (prefix)help commandname <- It wont appear then... If you want it embed you can do.

````py
class NewHelpName(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    async def send_pages(self):
        destination = self.get_destination()
        for page in self.paginator.pages:
            emby = discord.Embed(description=page)
            await destination.send(embed=emby)
client.help_command = NewHelpName()```
The built in help command is of great use
````