# How to make help command

Tags: python, discord.py

I made help command in python discord bot
but help cmd is alredy exist how to make help command?

```
@app.command()
async def help(ctx, helpcmd):
    if helpcmd == 'clear':
        (help embed or something)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove or change the default help command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951224/how-to-remove-or-change-the-default-help-command)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your own help command, make sure to add this to the top of your code:

```
app.remove_command('help')
```

That is the best way to make a custom help command. For more information, view this StackOverflow post: [How do I put discord.py help command in an embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092921/how-do-i-put-discord-py-help-command-in-an-embed)